# conditional subreport crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, conditional-statements, subreport

I have to display subreports based on condition, sometimes I need to display "Branch address" or "Customer address". I created these as subreports. How can I hide/show based on some condition ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your condition in the *Suppress* formula for the subreports.  If your condition evaluates to *true*, the subreport will not be printed.